# Github not verifying with OpenPGP key?

Tags: ssh, git, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

I generated a public/private key pair using GnuPG (following Github's instructions) and am getting the following error when trying to push my commit to a newly created repository:

```
git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have previously set up an SSH key for a remote server using the ssh keygen command and perhaps this is conflicting with my git although the github documentation told me to specify the OpenPGP key in config. The SSH key pair is in the `~/.ssh` folder under the names `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GnuPG and SSH serving different purpose within the git environment:

- SSH is used to secure the connection by encrypting it, but also providing authentication (thus, allowing access to a repository).
- GnuPG on the other hand allows you to sign commits and tags/releases. This allows others to make sure the commit has really been issued by you and not somebody else.

With other words: if you didn't register your public SSH key with Github, or did remove it there, you have no access to the repository. Add the content of your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file on Github to recover access through git.

Comment: Ok so GnuPG can't be used for providing authentication to Github in this case?

Comment: Actually you could use it together with an OpenPGP authentication subkey and the `ssh-agent`, but this is rather advanced usage of GnuPG. You'd still authenticate through SSH, and providing a converted SSH on GIthub. I would not recommend doing so just for the sake of using GnuPG though, the hassle does not provide a real advantage unless you start using some OpenPGP smartcards or similar technology.

Comment: Thank you. I'll bear this in mind further down the line when I'm more advanced :)